# How does the system go backward one path

Tags: c#, path

It's current path is `C:\Users\USERNAME\OneDrive\Desktop\Pro\Professional`

How do i set it to `C:\Users\USERNAME\OneDrive\Desktop\Pro`

But I don't set by writing string to set it back I want the system to understand where it is and go backwards.

Simply put I want it to be like the `cd..` command in Windows CMD.

Comment: Do you want to do this in code? What programming language are you using? Can you add more details on the context, where you want to do this?

Comment: My programming language I used is C#, But I already got the answer, thanks for your enthusiasm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the current directory, use

```
var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

To get the parent directory, use

```
var parentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(currentDirectory);
```

And finally to set the current directory:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(parentDirectory);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in `System.IO` called `Path.GetDirectoryName`. This would take your path as input and return the parent directory of the path which you have given.

Example:

```
string path = "C:\Users\USERNAME\OneDrive\Desktop\Pro\Professional";
string parentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

Here, the `parentDirectory` now contains `C:\Users\USERNAME\OneDrive\Desktop\Pro`.

If you want to go up multiple levels, you can call multiple times; e.g.,

```
string path = @"C:\Users\USERNAME\OneDrive\Desktop\Pro\Professional";
string parentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
```

The `parentDirectory` now contains `C:\Users\USERNAME\OneDrive\Desktop`.